# Firefox web console - network activity

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there any way to safe site network activity into variable?
I need all traffic like in network monitor tab.

Comment: There's no way (that I know of) to get EVERYTHING. You can get all the calls that use `fetch` by overriding it and saving every result into a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Firefox addon that makes the information available within a DevTools panel.

In particular, you would have to use the [devtools.network.getHAR()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools/network/getHAR) API.